# Disabling logging with LogLevel.None not working

Tags: postsharp

I have a project where Log aspect is applied for method entry and exit.

```
LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Backends.Console.ConsoleLoggingBackend();
```

To disable log, I have the below statement but I still see method entry, exit (which are LogLevel with Trace) in log

```
LoggingServices.DefaultBackend.GetSource(LoggingRoles.Tracing).SetLevel(LogLevel.None);
```

But when I change the loglevel to critical as below, the method entry/exit is not logged.

```
LoggingServices.DefaultBackend.GetSource(LoggingRoles.Tracing).SetLevel(LogLevel.Critical);
```

Shouldn't the LogLevel.None suppress the entry/exit traces ?

Comment: try LogLevel.OFF, if you want to disable logs in log4j it can be done by setting the level to OFF.  Just give a try I am not sure though, for this particular case.

Comment: LogLevel is an enum and has no OFF.

Comment: This looks like a bug. We'll get back to you when it's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in PostSharp 5.0.32.